# Does the switch_theme action run when you're upgrading a theme?

Tags: theme-development, actions

Did anyone test if this action is being executed on theme upgrade?
Are there any other actions I could use to attach a theme uninstall function?

Comment: No, i don't know, but i'm currently looking into it. I fav your Q and will head back here. Hope you update it too.

Comment: **"Does the switch_theme action run when you're upgrading a theme?"** I wouldn't have thought so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My educated guess is that process is implemented in [Theme_Upgrader](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L596) class.

It does some stuff with `upgrader_post_install` hook (seems like a good candidate) and it does run `switch_theme()` under some conditions (that I am too lazy to make sense of at moment).